# Create schema in Symfony 2 and Doctrine 2 with ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have some cross table between User table and Role table. I want to create cascade removing on the database level. I have the next annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_x_role",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 * @var ArrayCollection $roles
 */
protected $roles;
```

But foreign keys have ondelete=restrict and onupdate=restrict after:

```
doctrine:schema:update --force
```

How can I change these values to CASCADE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this, don't forget to modify also the cascade on ORM level.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_x_role",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 * )
 * @var ArrayCollection $roles
 */
protected $roles;
```